# How do I force rails to update a multiple select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, User and Group, with a many-to-many relationship between them.

```
has_many :groups, :through => :user_x_group
```

You can edit a user and select his groups in a select box, with multiple selection enabled.

However, when no groups are selected, the browser doesn't send the parameter in the request, and rails ignores any parameters not in the request, so in effect you cannot remove all of a user's groups.

Is there a way to specify to rails to update this field even if the parameter isn't sent?

Comment: delete_everything!!! unless params[:whatever].has_key? :somekey

Comment: Is that the actual method call?
Can you post a reference link?

Comment: the internet is at your service http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F